# How can I convince travis.ci to find Nashorn?

Tags: travis-ci, nashorn

I have a JVM-based project that uses the Nashorn Javascript engine.  It builds and tests locally fine.  When using travis.ci my unit tests explode with NullPointerExceptions because ScriptEngineManager.getEngineByName("nashorn") is returning null.

Here's the travis.yml I'm using:

```
language: scala

scala:
   - 2.11.8

notifications:
  email:
    recipients:
      - info@blocke.com

jdk:
  - oraclejdk8

script:
  - sbt clean coverage test coverageReport && sbt coverageAggregate

before_install:
  - export TZ=America/Chicago
  - date

after_success:
  - sbt coverageReport coveralls

addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - oracle-java8-installer
```

Answer (score 0):

Moving to oraclejdk11 solved the problem!